# realtime notifications with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a problem with my PHP project.
Users should get realtime notifications (something like facebook or google+, that shows users a "count" which stands for new / unread notifications).

This is, how I did it in the past:
AJAX call (every x seconds) -> server (php) -> response (a number, that stands for all new notifications) -> JQuery (modify html page).

I don't really like the idea, to send an ajax call every x seconds.

What is the best way to create real realtime features? (I heard, that there is socket.io, but how can I / can I use it with PHP)?

Thanks :)

Comment: Those all work with a websocket connection which is as real time client/server communication as possible. It is typically done with NodeJS, but there are socket servers for PHP ([ratchet](http://socketo.me/)). Socket.io works with NodeJS, not php. It is a little more complicated to work with, though IMHO not hard and would require a private server (vps or dedicated) instead of a shared server. Another option which is similar to ajax is also long polling if you wanted another alternative.

Comment: Just use websockets. There are a lot of implementations for any language. Pick one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your options having a PHP server are rather limited while by itself Apache cannot hold connections and a [Long Polling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology) implementation is therefore infeasible, which makes realtime push infeasible.

However, the simplest solution is to easily utilize one of the existing **Push Services**, they will direct notify the user of any events occurring server-side.

Other than that, you could still look into an implementation of **Websockets** for **Apache** or any other web server that you might be using. For instance, this one: [apache-websocket](https://github.com/disconnect/apache-websocket)